# What is the type for an object that contains only boolean values in React TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have some code that I wrote in React JavaScript that has now been migrated over to TypeScript and I'm not entirely sure what to declare the type as. I preferably don't want to use the type `any`:

```
  const [responseStatus, setResponseStatus] = React.useState<any>({
    emptyResponse: true,
    unsuccessfulResponse: false,
    successfulResponse: false,
    badResponse: false
  });
```

Comment: Just create `interface ResponseStatus { emptyResponse: boolean, unsuccessfulResponse: boolean..`

Comment: You may append each property name that may be not present with `?` to make it optional and then apply that type: `useState<ResponseStatus>`

Comment: Thank you will give it a try! Another quick question - if I have a variable that contains a JSON object - do you perhaps know what that variable type should be?

Comment: Or if you don't know what the keys will be, maybe `{ [key: string]: boolean }`. And no, we can't tell you what the variable for some random JSON object would be, because we have *no idea what's in it*.

Comment: You could also use [`Record<string, boolean>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Set the type as a Record

```js
type ResponseType = Record<string, boolean>;

const Component: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [responseStatus, setResponseStatus] = React.useState<ResponseType>({
    emptyResponse: true,
    unsuccessfulResponse: false,
    successfulResponse: false,
    badResponse: false
  });

  return (
    <div>{responseStatus.emptyResponse}</div>
  )
}
```

2. Make an interface for the state

```js
interface ResponseStatus {
  [key: string]: boolean;
}

const Component: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [responseStatus, setResponseStatus] = React.useState<ResponseStatus>({
    emptyResponse: true,
    unsuccessfulResponse: false,
    successfulResponse: false,
    badResponse: false
  });

  return (
    <div>{responseStatus.emptyResponse}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: @jam_swagger: just be aware that while this solution may be tempting as the least verbose, it doesn't give you that much of a type safety (even compared to `any`), since it won't check neither for specific properties present/missing, nor (what's more important) for correct property names.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov you're absolutely right, but sometimes Record constructions could be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be very specific:

```
interface ResponseStatus {
  [key: 'emptyResponse' | 'unsuccessfulResponse' | 'successfulResponse' | 'badResponse' ]: boolean;
}
```

Otherwise Oleg's answer above should do it :)

Comment: If you seek for a way to attain certain type safety and fully benefit from TypeScript, I would say, you **have to** be as much specific as possible, whenever possible Otherwise, the use of TS becomes only formal and it's just a pointless hassle about some extra code.